# Rate callback while scan with BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I scan using `ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY`.
When I start my application I have a high rate callback but when the screen goes Off the rate drops too much.

I’m testing on Samsung S7 Android 7.0

Can anybody explain why it does and how can keep the same high rate when screen is On as much as when the screen Off ?

I need to get the callback at least every 300ms.